# How to retrieve longitude/latitude from a text file or CSV when using leaflet js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, csv, leaflet

I'm new to all of this and have been playing about with an idea, however I am stuck,

I would like to create a map with leaflet with markers and polygons, My question is can you retrieve the longitude/latitude from an external file.

so that I could update this file occasionally and new data would appear on the map, if you guys know a better way, I'm all ears.

Appreciate any guidance you can provide, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, most common would be using geojson file and making new layer.
There are plenty of guides how to do that. 1 is here http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Next time do more searching and we can avoid such questions.

Good luck,
Kristjan